# Arduino not in sync unique error

Tags: arduino-uno

[image: Fritzing diagram]

When I try uploading to my Arduino/Genuino UNO I get the following not in sync error with "unique" resp(resp=0X54) or (resp=0X81) please solve ... I have to submit my project tommorow......

> error message:
>   avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
>   avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x54
>   avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
>   avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x54
>   avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
>   avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x54
>   avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
>   avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x54
>   avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
>   avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x54
>   avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
>   avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x54
>   avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
>   avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x54
>   avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
>   avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x54
>   avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
>   avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x54
>   avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
>   avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x54
>   Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: I think this is more likely to get an accurate answer on the stackexchange Arduino forum. So would you ask it there? Have you tried something much simpler, like uploading the 'Blink' example?

Comment: Are you able to compile code? Are you using arduino board? If yes, disconnect external circuitry and try uploading the code. If it works, re-check your external circuit. If it doesn't, replace your arduino. If you are not using arduino board, let us know. Also, it's always a good idea to show us the circuit/ schematic etc. Help us help you.

Comment: i have uploadeed the schematic and the code

Comment: Have you previously *successfully* loaded a program using this same computer and same Arduino? Is it possible that the software has changed since then? Have you access to a 2nd Arduino or 2nd computer? Is this computer in a classroom? Please post the whole text of the new error message.

Answer (score 3):

You have a BT module attached to Arduino Tx Rx pins. That's the culprit. Disconnect anything from Tx and Rx pins of arduino while uploading code. Once the code has been uploaded, re-connect the BT module.

Edit:

Since this didn't solve your problem, you need to pin point the issue. If you have removed everything from Arduino and still not able to upload the code - either your drivers are not up to date or your arduino is faulty.

Test the arduino:

Try uploading blinky sketch. Didn't succeed? Restart arduino IDE and try again. Didn't succeed? Restart PC and try again. Didn't succeed? Re install arduino and try again? Didn't succeed? Try on a friend's PC? No luck? Arduino is faulty.

Note: This answer is for the exact schematic you have given. If you have done something else, there might be other reasons why you are not able to upload the code. Post a real picture of what exactly you are doing and we might be able to help you further.

Comment: Yup. You beat me to it, but that's all I would have written too. +1

Comment: i did that mistake but i removed all the wires from arduino and tries to reupload but the same happens

Comment: please reply Whiskeyjack and gbulmer

Comment: So you get the same error with *ALL* wires disconnected except for the USB lead? Are you *SURE* you have selected the correct board and port? If you have. I would disconnect the Arduino from the USB port, reboot the PC, and try loading Blink. It is *possible* (but unusual) that you have damaged the Arduino's Rx or Tx pin or the USB-to-UART's pins.

Comment: @gbulmer - What sorcery is this? Are you a mind reader or something? :)

Comment: @gbulmer i tries rebooting but the same error bur this time with(resp=0Xe6)...

Comment: @Whiskeyjack - I teach Arduino stuff every week to children from 12-16. These incantations become reflexes :-)

Comment: please answer i get different resp no i got(resp=0Xob)

Comment: Attach the real image. You might be hiding too much useful info by assuming we don't need that to answer your question. For ex - Whether you are using arduino UNO or Arduino Pro mini, whether you bought one or made one using atmega 328.

Answer (score 3):

NOTE

That schematic shows you are trying to power the motors from the Arduino's 5V power supply. That is a 'bad idea' unless they are good quality, low-current, motors.

The electrical noise from the motors may cause the Arduino to reset, and run the same program from the beginning until it reaches the part where the motor's electrical noise resets it.

Worse, current drawn if the motors stall may damage the Arduino's power supply. The Arduino's voltage regulator is supposed to protect itself from damage, but it doesn't always succeed. This is rare, but I have had students break it.

I have elevated this comment to an answer to warn other people against trying to use the schematic in the question.

Comment: uare a genius .. after 2 hours of research, i found that my arduino is bricked and the bootloader is curropt. i ave to buy avr usbasp cuz that is the cheapest . to reupload the bootloader ........thanks ...........................

Comment: It is possible to get the same chip working if you try re uploading the bootloader to it. I have seen it in a few cases. Use the arduino bootloader burning guide to do so.

Comment: @AnirudhRaghavanS - if you already have access to another Arduino, you can use that to reload the bootloader.

Comment: @gbulmer  i dont have another arduino so the cheapest programmer in the the market is avr usbasp which costs around 3 dollars , so i am thinking of buying that stuff, anyway thanks

Comment: @whickeyjack i dont have another arduino so the cheapest programmer in the the market is avr usbasp which costs around 3 dollars , so i am thinking of buying that stuff, anyway thanks – Anirudh Raghavan S just now

Comment: @gbulmer and whiskeyjack\ , please give me your facebook id, i want to have you as a guide for my arduino project